# Best way to handle a question that was half caused by a typo

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Earlier I asked the following question: [NET 5 Top-level programs in preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955905/net-5-top-level-programs-in-preview?noredirect=1#comment111331517_62955905), about an issue I was facing with a new preview function in C# 9. During my own debugging I found that different ways of compiling the project resulted in two different errors, but both failing to compile.

One of these issues was correctly spotted by an answerer as a typo. Fixing said typo would allow me to compile the project with one of the two methods, but still fail on the other. I received a close vote for `not reproducibble or was caused by typos` which i fully support, and put in my own close reason for that as well (the question is now locked). However the "core" issue of the question still remains (the issue that isn't just a dumb typo by me).

Now I am unsure of what the proper action moving forward with this question is, having considered the following options:

**Edit the part containing the typo, and focussing the question on the non-typo part:**
I don't like this option because it invalidates the current (correct) answer, and in general questions shouldn't be edited in such a way that it fixes a problem posed in the original question.

**(Edit out the second issue i'm still facing) Ask a new question focussing solely on the issue still at hand:**
This one could be done two ways:

- Editing out the second error so the current question only focusses on the typo part, leaving behind a rather meaningless and unhelpful question. (Currently I would consider this the least harmful option)
- Leaving this question as it is, and ask a new question that is focussed on the error that is still there. This would mean I create a duplicate of my own question (even if just partially), which also doesn't sit well with me either.

**Ask for deletion of the question and ask a new one:**
There is an answer on the post with upvotes. This is stopping me from deleting the answer myself, although even if I could delete it myself I don't think that would be the solution anyway. Someone still took the time to help me with the silly mistake, and they should be rewarded accordingly for it.

**Leave it as it is, and move on with my life:**
I don't feel this is the way to go at all, as the core issue of the question is still there. However no one can add new answers to it that may address this issue because of the (deserved) lock on the question. And it would hinder other people from asking about the genuine problem because it would technically be a duplicate...

I realise now that the question was a poorly asked one to begin with (too broad), as it turned out the two different errors on compiling via different methods had two completely different sources, and not the same source I thought it had that I used as a premise to ask the question on.

What would be the proper course of action here, so that I don't have to ask a duplicate question, nor invalidate the current answerers correct answer?

Comment: A 13k user really ought to know better than to answer a question that should have been closed...

Comment: I have decided that asking for a mod to delete the post was the best course of action here, which has now been done.

Answer (score 2):

Ask a new question with the specific issue. You could also link the old question for context

Comment: Remy can't delete the question because it has an upvoted answer, but I have to ask what does a question whose answer is just a typo contribute to Stack Overflow, or in other words what information would actually be lost by deleting it? (Remy has 3.4K rep, so is presumably not in danger of getting Q-banned)

Comment: I agree that deleting it doesn't lose the site any meaningful information, neither am I afraid of a question ban. However I cannot as mentioned.